# MySQL:[Warning] Invalid (old?) table or database name '#sql140c_91291_6'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Version: 5.6.10

NB:The table storage engine is INNODB

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8164/mysql-bug-required-remedy-warning-invalid-old-table-or-database-name-sq

Comment: Its a bug in MySQL version 5.1.22 but my server is running on 5.6.10 .